# Google App Script - Drop Down based on another sheet plus grab corresponding data on other sheet

Tags: google-apps-script, checkbox, drop-down-menu, google-sheets-formula

I am struggling to find example Google App Sheets code for a QUERY() that runs when user selects a "Name" in the drop down. Then, displays the corresponding "Address" in the next column.
(Ideally, it would also show the address in the dropdown to distinguish one name from another)

Sheet1 = "Expenses"
Sheet2 = "SharedList_Hidden"  (hidden sheet in same file w/ Col1 = Name, Col2 = Address)

Additional Goal:
Using a checkbox, remove the dropdown, so user can enter a name & address that are not in the list.

What is the best way to accomplish this?
The name list has about 400 rows.

Also, should I be using OnSelectionChange or OnEdit when they pick an item in the dropdown and I want to show the address in the next column or a calculation based on them?

```
//This is the query I was using within the cells in column D on the sheet originally. 
//=IFERROR(QUERY(SharedList_Hidden!$A$2:$B$500,"Select B Where A='" & $C18 & "'"),)

//This is my first attempt at formatting the query within App Sheet
//var query_formula = '=QUERY(' + data_range + ', "select B where A='" + xxx + "'",1)'


/***** POPULATE DROPDOWN*********(This works for one column!)********************

function dropdownFromAnotherFile(){

let originWS=SpreadsheetApp.openById("...")
let originSS=originWS.getSheetByName("SharedFacilityList")
let originData=originSS.getDataRange().getValues()

//Removes the header
originData.shift()

//gets an array of arrays and change to array since dropdown only uses simple array (from [[0][2]] to [0][2])
let stylesArray=originData.map(row=>row[0])

let dataValidation=SpreadsheetApp.newDataValidation()
.requireValueInList(stylesArray).build()

let destinyWS=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
let destinySS=destinyWS.getSheetByName("Expenses")
destinySS.getRange("C18:C").setDataValidation(dataValidation)
//destinySS.getRange("B18:B").clearDataValidations(dataValidation)
}

/**********Attempting to look at checkbox and show or hide the dropdown
// It successfully enters the if statement and displays True or false, but doesn't affect dropdown

function onEdit(e){
const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
const sh = e.source.getActiveSheet();
const r = e.source.getActiveRange();

if(e.value== "TRUE"){ // capital TRUE or FALSE is important
    ss.toast('True');
    deleteDropdown()
} else {
    ss.toast('False');
    createDropdown_FromRange()  
}
}

/*** Here are the functions for creating and deleting dropdowns
/* I moved the data so the cell references are currently wrong

function deleteDropdown(){
const ss= SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
const sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Expenses");

const cell= sheet.getrange("B12");
cell.clearDatavalidations();

}
//SharedList_Hidden
function createDropdown_FromRange(){
const ss= SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
const sheet = ss.getSheetByName("SharedList_Hidden");

const cell= sheet.getRange("B12");
const rangeList = ss.getRange("'SharedList_Hidden'!A2:A")
const rule = SpreadsheetApp.newDataValidation().requireValueInRange(rangeList).build();
cell.setDataValidation(rule);
}`
```

Comment: `1)` The `QUERY` works so I'm confused about `I am struggling... ` `2)`  `it would also show the address in the dropdown to distinguish one name from another`: Create an extra column that combines the name and address and use this column for Data validation `3)` `Using a checkbox, remove the dropdown, so user can enter a name & address that are not in the list.` I'm confused, what is the purpose of entering a name and address not on the list? Do do you want to add it to the list? Is it really necessary to delete/reinstate the data validation?

Comment: checkbox w/ on/off of drop down is no longer necessary. My goal: User picks from drop down list or puts "other". Then, address appears, mileage is calculated. Ideally: drop downs show name & address (like MS Access bound column= id, but shows any other fields you want). Columns = A(Date), B(Facility), C(Address= retrieved from other sheet), D(Mileage Calc), E(Park/Toll $), F(Line Total). D & F are calculated within Google App Script. What are best practices for clean code that looks up data on another sheet per user selection in a drop down. Lookup has 420 rows and is identical to drop downs.